# Getting creation date from a message from channel.history

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I searched and searched to somehow maybe find a solution but either it just doesn't work (what I don't believe) or just nobody asked because it's too obvious.

I need the creation date of a message to save it and check at the next run all the messages from this creation date (my bot is down over night and sometimes also at day).

## What I tried

I tried it with `channel.history(limit=1).flatten()[0].created_at`, `channel.history(limit=1).created_at`, `for message in channel.history(limit=1): lastmsg = message.created_at` and so on.

## My code

My current code is:

```
async def save_last_msg(bot):
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

    for message in channel.history(limit=1):
        lastmsg = message.created_at

    jsonhandle.update("last_message", lastmsg, "lastmsg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`channel.history` is an `async` iterator, it's pretty clear how to use it in the docs:

```py
async for message in channel.history(limit=1):
    lastmsg = message.created_at
```

Using the `.flatten` method

```py
lastmsg = (await channel.history(limit=1).flatten())[0].created_at
```

Comment: I've actually tried that with the .flatten and it didn't work but the upper thing works xD Just that one async thing...

Comment: Ik, you just have to wait 10mins until you can